# How to create a horizontally-centered DIV which has a minimum width but can stretch out as needed?

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a site layout with a fixed header, a fixed footer and a central content section; this is a sample HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="Header">
        Header Text
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
        Content Text
    </div>
    <div class="Footer">
        Footer Text
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my current CSS:

```
.Header
{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:50px;
    left:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:1000px;
}

.Content
{
    border:1px solid black;
    bottom:60px;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:60px;
}

.Footer
{
    border:1px solid black;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
    left:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    width:1000px;
}
```

This works well for the header and footer, which have a fixed width; however, I can't find a way to make the content section stick in the center of the screen, unless I give it a fixed width too.
I need the content section to have a minimum size equal to the header and footer, but sometimes it needs to display wider content, thus I also need it to be able to stretch horizontally if needed, up to the full browser width; in all situations, it has to stay horizontally centered.
I tried various combinations of positioning parameters (including `min-width`,`margin-left`,`margin-right`,`width:auto` and so on), but nothing seems to work unless I give the DIV a fixed width too; but then, when wider content is displayed, this will force horizontal scrolling even if the browser window is actually large enough to display all of it.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Give the content a min-width and center it with margin

```
.Content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmYWQ/)

Comment: Doesn't work, with this it always stretches to the full browser width, even if the content is small; I need it to stay at the minimum width unless the content is actually wider than that.